# ZF: js is recognized but does not work in action views

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I'm having a problem with javascript, I can see the `<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>` in the code source of the `http://localhost/application/public/controller/action` action views but that js function does not really work and in the `"http://localhost/application/public/controller/"` pages everything works correctly!!
Can anyone plz help me.
 My js files are called in the `layout.phtml`, this javascript function enables the display of 3 pictures as a slide show and it works in all controller pages i mean `http://localhost/application/public/controller/` pages but only in the action views it don't work although i still can see it in the code source of all pages

Comment: What does the JS function do? Do you get any javascript errors? In what way does it 'not really work?' Please edit you question to include more info.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the issue seems to be with the path of JS.

Without seeing the code, I am just guessing that you have probably not used baseUrl view helper.

In your layout.phtml, try to call your Images, JS and CSS using the baseUrl helper http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl

Assuming you are storing all your js files in a folder called js in your public folder.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $this->baseUrl('js/xyz.js'); ?>'></script>
```

Please let me know if this does not solve your problem.